# How to determine end behavior with my TI-83

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

So, I need to determine the end behavior of $P$ for this equation:

$$P(x) = −x^5 + 3x^2 + x.$$

If possible, how is this done?

Comment: What do you mean by "end behavior" of a polynomial?

Comment: @jak: Taken care of...

Comment: @myself: Nevermind...I see now that since P has an even degree and negative leading coefficient, its end behavior will look like this... 
y → - ∞ as x → ∞  and y →  ∞ as x → - ∞  

Reading is fundamental I suppose.

Comment: @Brandt The end behavior you wrote down is correct for $P$, but it has odd degree, not even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title asks how to determine the end behavior (also called limiting behavior) with a calculator, so I will speak to that.

**Hasty Answer**

To determine behavior as $x$ tends toward positive infinity, plug in a giant positive value for $x$. If the polynomial results in a positive (respectively, negative) value for that $x$, then the polynomial tends toward positive (respectively, negative) infinity.

To determine behavior as $x$ tends toward negative infinity, plug in a giant negative value for $x$. If the polynomial results in a positive (respectively, negative) value for that $x$, then the polynomial tends toward positive (respectively, negative) infinity.

**Caveat**

An important fact about polynomials: The maximum number of roots a polynomial can have is equal to the degree. For your example, this means at most five roots (possibly less).

To be *absolutely sure* you've determined your end behavior properly, you need to be sure the giant positive and negative $x$'s you picked is beyond (i.e. farther away from the origin than) all of the roots. In practice, however, plugging in something like $x = 10^{100}$ and $x = -10^{100}$ (or whatever your calculator can handle without exploding) will be *well* beyond the roots.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial takes on all values of $x$. So you could just find all the roots and graph.

Standard methods won't get you anywhere because there is only one integer solution.

On [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E5%20%2b%203x%5E2%20%2b%20x%20=%200), I get a plot from $x \in [-1.5,2]$

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean these?
$$\lim_{-\infty} P = +\infty\ \text{ and }\ \lim_{+\infty}P=-\infty$$
This is basically because $x^5$ is the *leading* summand and it is taken with negative coefficient ($-1$). 
For $x$ of large absolute value, since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^k}{x^5} = 0$ for $k<5$, so
$$\lim_{\pm\infty} P = \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} -x^5(1-\frac{3x^2+x}{x^5}) = \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} -x^5 $$